# For a particle in a 1D box, what is the expectation value of momentum for a particle that has tunnelled through the walls and escaped?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, potential, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

For a particle in a box, where the walls of the box have a finite (i.e. not infinite) potential
energy, what is the expectation value of the momentum of a particle which has tunnelled
through the wall and has escaped?

Comment: It depends on the thickness of the walls. You’ll need to be a bit more precise with your setup

Comment: I don't think it does depend on the thickness of the walls? Do you have a justification for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a lot of insight to be gained in discussing $\langle P\rangle$, especially without a specific situation in mind. But I can discuss how the conservation of energy tells us something about the kinetic energy of the particle after escaping a finite barrier. Hopefully that helps with the intuition of the state of a particle post-quantum tunnelling.

Consider this version of your question:
[image]

I start with a wavefunction localized in the box - the red line. In this case, it's most convenient to think of tunnelling out of the box in the following way:

My red particle is not an eigenstate of the full Hamiltonian. It should be instead imagined as a sum of the continuum eigenstates of the full hamiltonian (an example is shown - crudely - in green).

After a lot of time goes by, the particle will be located mostly outside of the box - the original sum had cancellation between a bunch of amplitudes outside of the box, and as time evolution acts on these states, the cancellation will disappear and the amplitude outside of the box will no longer be zero.

The expectation value of energy can be, in general, calculated in two different ways. In the early system, it should be calculated as
$$
\int_x \psi(x) (d^2/dx^2) \psi(x)  dx
$$
An integral over x that you can complete to find the expectation value of this energy. In the late time system, it should be thought of as
$$
\int \phi(p)p^2\phi(p)dp
$$
An integral over the kinetic energies of the plane waves (moving away from the box) that the particle became. ($\phi$ is the momentum space wavefunction)

Schrodinger's equation tells us that the expectation value of energy doesn't change with time. So the average kinetic energy the particle has as it moves away from the box that it tunneled out of is the same as the energy it had when it was in the box. We came a long way to arrive at such a simple conclusion.

Comment: OP asks about the expectation value of momentum. Which of course can only be predicted after we know much more information than just "the particle was detected in the box at some time in the past".

Comment: I kind of reinterpreted the question as "how do we understand the kinetic energy of a particle that was once quasi-trapped then quantum tunneled away." It seemed clear to me, given the lack of an exact potential and initial state, that OP wasn't specifically asking for someone to calculate $\langle P\rangle$ in a particular system, but was instead looking for some insight into the nature of a particle after quantum tunneling.

Comment: @AndrewChristensen clearly the expectation value of momentum is not the same as that of the kinetic energy… moreover your model is not really a particle in a box with finite potential energy…

Comment: Yeah I took creative liberties with reinterpreting the question - and it seems some people thought I took too many. I only put a finite potential wall on one side because otherwise $\langle p\rangle$ is just trivially zero forever because of symmetry. I tried to discuss what could be reasonably discussed given the vagueness of the question. I didn't think anything definite could be said about $P$, but one could discuss how conservation of energy says something about $P^2$. I'm hoping that gives an improved intuitive picture of the particle post-tunneling.